# Template element fails with some script tags

Tags: javascript, html

I create template and insert some html from string.

I know I can use innerHTML, but I am wondering why the following example fails using template?  (even if I remove backslashes the same result)

In the end, only first script tag is added inside ".a" element.

```js
var adContent = '<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"><\/script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="AD_CLIENT_HERE" data-ad-slot="AD_SLOT_HERE"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});<\/script>'
  

var a = document.querySelector('.a'),

ad = htmlToElement(adContent)

//var clean = adContent.replace('\\', '');
//ad = htmlToElement(clean)

a.append(ad)


function htmlToElement (html) {
        var template = document.createElement('template');
        html = html.trim(); 
        template.innerHTML = html;
        return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: If I add an additional `ad = htmlToElement(); a.append(ad)` to your code it results in two script tags as child elements of `.a`. So I'm not sure what your actual problem is ...

Comment: You can see adContent is not added completely.